# Making HTML page redirection based on the text input of form

Tags: html

Making a little search engine. The idea is to take input from the user and then based on that, make a redirection to the search page.

The following code:

```
<form action ="/search.html">
     <label for="form-search"></label>
     <input type="text" id="form-search" placeholder="TYPE HERE!"><hr>
     <input type="submit" name="query" value="Search!">
</form>
```

Always redirects to the following page regardless of what the input user has given:

/search.html?query=++Search%21++

While (for the input "Suppose This Was Entered") it should go to:

/search.html?query=Suppose++This++Was++Entered

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Search%21 = "Search!" ... you set it as the value. Possibly you meant `placeholder="Search!"` rather than value.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Keeping that "Search!" as placeholder makes the redirection to the following page:

[link](search.html?query=Submit)

I want this "Submit" to be replaced by user input.

Comment: You seem to be missing something from your comment. The point is that you have set the value as 'Search!'. Therefore if you try to redirect to the value, it will go to Search%21 because that's what you set.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yeah, sorry, I just edited it. All I'm trying to do is to NOT set anything by default (nothing like "Search!" or "Submit") and rather whatever the user enters in the form-search, I want that particular keyword in the redirected URL.

Comment: You added the `html` tag only. Is Javascript allowed?

Comment: @Ivan86 It'd be awesome if you can tell me what I should include in the <script> part to do what I'm trying to do.

Feeling so noob ATM.

Comment: @Zuberi I posted a solution, let me know if it works for you. I removed the `name` attribute from the `button`, and added an `id` to the form so it can be easily accessible in Javascript.

Comment: @Ivan86 Your code as well as YasielCabrera's code, both seem to be working just about right! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @zuberi you're welcome. Glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var name used in the query string of the url is the `name` attribute of the form fields so you need add a `name` atribute to your `text` field instead to the submit input.

```
<form action ="/search.html">
   <label for="query"></label>
   <input type="text" id="query" name="query" placeholder="TYPE HERE!"><hr>
   <input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
```

The id and the name in the text field not necessary has to be the same

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that gets called when the form submits via the form's `onsubmit` attribute. From within the funciton you can manipulate your URL generation like below:

Note: `return false;` is to prevent submitting the form since the return value of the function is passed to the form's `onsubmit`.

```js
function submitFunction() {

  let searchText = document.getElementById("form-search").value.trim();
  let form = document.getElementById('myForm');

  if(searchText.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("s").value = searchText;
    form.action = "/search.html";
    form.submit();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of Your page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return submitFunction();">
     <label for="form-search"></label>
     <input type="text" id="form-search" placeholder="TYPE HERE!" value="" >
     <input type="hidden" id="s" name="query" value="" />
     <hr>
     <input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```